values on Y-axis displaying as CI and not actual dependent variable values
I'm having troubles with my code - I would like to plot a scatterplot of my dependent variable Weight against my independent variable rainfall - then fit a geom_line and then confidence intervals
however - when I plot my graph - the values on the y axis are displaying as the CI calculated with emmeans and not as the actual weight values - I can't see where i'm going wrong. Then I wanted to fit a line and then display confidence intervals if possible. Any help would be amazing thank you!
Here is my code:
emm <- emmeans(SBB2024, ~ `Rainfall(mm)`, type = "response")
#summary(emm)
emm_summary <-summary(emm, infer = TRUE)

upper.CL <- emm_summary$upper.CL
lower.CL <- emm_summary$lower.CL

plot(emm)

plot_model_data = emmeans (SBB2024, ~ `Rainfall(mm)`, at  = list (`Rainfall(mm)` = 24.8:318))
plot_model_data <- as.data.frame(plot_model_data)

data_plot = ggplot (MLMtimemonths, aes(x = `Rainfall(mm)`, y = LOGweight)) + geom_point()

data_plot + geom_line(data = plot_model_data, aes(x = `Rainfall(mm)`, y = LOGweight))

data_plot <- ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = MLMtimemonths, aes(x = `Rainfall(mm)`, y = LOGweight)) +  
  geom_line(data = plot_model_data, aes(x = `Rainfall(mm)`, y = emmean)) +  
  xlab("Cummulative rainfall (mm) over 12 months prior to sampling") +   
  ylab("Weight (g)")     

print(data_plot)

That output gives me the values for the CI as the Y- axis which is not what i'm after. At the least I just need to be able to plot the graph with a fitted line - CI is just a bonus

I'm not sure what you are seeing. But here is a similar example using the pigs dataset in emmeans. I found that I needed to add a group aesthetic to make it work.
mod = lm(conc ~ source + factor(percent), data = pigs)
EMM = emmeans(mod, "source")
ggplot() + geom_point(data = pigs, aes(x = source, y = conc)) +
    geom_line(data = as.data.frame(EMM), aes(x = source, y = emmean, group = 1))


